# Using linq to find best match across multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, filtering

I am trying to use linq to find the best match in a list of custom objects across a set of properties. In the list of MyObjects created below, I want to find the one that most closely matches testObject across all four of MyObject's properties:

```
IList<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "B", Property3 = "C", Property4 = "D" });
list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "C", Property4 = "D" });
list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "A", Property4 = "D" });


var testObject = new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "A", Property4 = "A" };
```

In the example above, I would want to match the last object as 3 or the 4 properties match the properties in testObject.

I can work out how many attributes there is a match for by doing this:

```
 var matchCount = list.Max(x => (x.Property1 == testObject.Property1 ? 1 : 0) +
        (x.Property2 == testObject.Property2 ? 1 : 0) +
        (x.Property3 == testObject.Property3 ? 1 : 0) +
        (x.Property4 == testObject.Property4 ? 1 : 0));
```

But I can't figure out how to then pick up the entity that matches on three of the properties other than writing out a very long linq expression that checks for 3 matches on each combination of properties. Ideally, I'd like a solution that works elegantly for objects with 10 properties.

Does anyone know if there is an accepted way of doing this?

## Edit

An additional piece of information that I missed from my original question... If there is more than 1 object that matches then I need to select the list of objects that match with that level of accuracy (i.e. if there is one object that matches on 3 properties, then I need to find all the objects that match on 3 properties)

## solution

Based on Sloths answer, I have been able to get what I wanted using this. I'd be interested to see if anyone has a neater answer to this though...

```
var grouping = list.GroupBy(x => (x.Property1 == testObject.Property1 ? 1 : 0) +
(x.Property2 == testObject.Property2 ? 1 : 0) +
(x.Property3 == testObject.Property3 ? 1 : 0) +
(x.Property4 == testObject.Property4 ? 1 : 0));

var maxCount = grouping.Max(x => x.Key);
var resultSet = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == maxCount).Select(g => g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this

```
    IList<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

    list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "B", Property3 = "C", Property4 = "D" });
    list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "C", Property4 = "D" });
    list.Add(new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "A", Property4 = "D" });


    var testObject = new MyObject { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A", Property3 = "A", Property4 = "A" };

//list of objects with 3 or matches
    var sorted = list.Select(x => new
    {
        MatchCount = (x.Property1 == testObject.Property1 ? 1 : 0)
                    + (x.Property2 == testObject.Property2 ? 1 : 0)
                    + (x.Property3 == testObject.Property3 ? 1 : 0)
                    + (x.Property4 == testObject.Property4 ? 1 : 0),
        MyObj = x
    })
    .OrderBy( x => x.MatchCount)
    .Where( x => x.MatchCount >= 3 );

//gets the first object from the list
    var match = sorted.Any() ? sorted.OrderBy(x => x.MatchCount).FirstOrDefault().MyObj : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some good old reflection:

```
// get all get methods of all public properties
var getter = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.GetMethod).ToList();

// sort by number of matches
var result = list.OrderBy(l => getter.Count(a => a.Invoke(l, null).Equals(a.Invoke(testObject, null)))).LastOrDefault();
```

Not the fastet approach, but simple.

---

In response to your comment:

Just use a `GroupBy`:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(l => getter.Count(a => a.Invoke(l, null).Equals(a.Invoke(testObject, null))))
                  .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
                  .LastOrDefault();
```

`grouped` now contains all items with the best match.

Comment: Thanks Sloth. This would solve the problem in the case where there is one best match. I've updated my question to explain that I also need to handle the case where there are multiple matches with equal accuracy and I'm not sure that this apporach can be extending to cover that use case.

Comment: See my edit. Just replace `OrderBy` with `GroupBy`, then do the ordering afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Matson answer is good but maybe splitting implementation of propertyMatches and linq query is better for [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) and gives you more readable queries.

Also, you can return MyObject directly from the linq query.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Program
{
    public static void Main()

    {
        IList<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

        list.Add(new MyObject { P1 = "A", P2 = "B", P3 = "C", P4 = "D" });
        list.Add(new MyObject { P1 = "A", P2 = "A", P3 = "C", P4 = "D" });
        list.Add(new MyObject { P1 = "A", P2 = "A", P3 = "A", P4 = "D" });

        var testObject = new MyObject { P1 = "A", P2 = "A", P3 = "A", P4 = "A" };

       //create a list of annonymous class with inner MyObject and propertyMatches count, filter it by matches and return its inner MyObject
       //I think this query is easy to read, returs what you want (list of MyObject) in one line and can be applied without changes to any class as long implements propertyMatches.
        var res = from ao in (from obj in list select new { obj = obj, matches = obj.propertyMatches(testObject) }) where ao.matches >= 3 select ao.obj;

      //same query in method call form
      var res2 = list.Select(o => new
          {
             matches = o.propertyMatches(testObject),
             obj = o
          }).Where(ao => ao.matches >= 3).Select(ao => ao.obj);

        Console.WriteLine(res.First().P1);
        Console.WriteLine(res.First().P2);
        Console.WriteLine(res.First().P3);
        Console.WriteLine(res.First().P4);

        Console.WriteLine(res2.First().P1);
        Console.WriteLine(res2.First().P2);
        Console.WriteLine(res2.First().P3);
        Console.WriteLine(res2.First().P4);

    }
}
```

`propertyMatches` could be abstract method in base class of MyObject, or interface method or extension method or whatever you need, depends of your design and architecture.

i.e.

```
 public static class oMyExtensions
        {
            public static int propertyMatches(this MyObject o, MyObject otherObj)
            {
                return (o.P1 == otherObj.P1 ? 1 : 0)
                + (o.P2 == otherObj.P2 ? 1 : 0)
                + (o.P3 == otherObj.P3 ? 1 : 0)
                + (o.P4 == otherObj.P4 ? 1 : 0);

            }
        }
```

Complete example [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/isq2kP).